# How do I incorporate an Android emulator for my React Native project?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

How would I use an Android emulator when I'm working on a project in React Native?  Right now, I can successfully run an iOS emulator with no problems in my project.  But when it comes to Android, whenever I run `react-native run-android`, I get an error that says I don't have an Android emulator.

I have `BlueStacks` (found it by Googling) on my Mac but not really sure what I should do with it.

Comment: Did you read the [Getting Started docs for Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment)?

Comment: use android emulator from android SDK

Answer (score 0):

use adb command to watch ur android devices. open command line and type

```
cd  c:/sdk/platorm-tools

adb devices
```

adb is loacted in sdk folder in platform-tools. if u have not any device use a android phone for check ur app. but enable u developer option in setting of android phone.